# How to get filename in awk

Tags: awk

I have a zip file with below name and record:

- Filename : OMS_Profile_20150922.list.Z

Sample Record:

```
1234568194|301776931|301344831|301745924|4000247920|5|1|14|
1234525025|300667099|300316999|300645099|300624099|5|1|14|
1234586176|301121638|301131238|301145638|301124638|5|1|14|
1234597373|300689187|345664087|302464187|300624187|5|1|21|
```

Now I want to get the below desired output by `awk` command:

```
field1|field6|field7|field8|OMS_Profile_20150922.list.Z
```

Comment: Please research a bit before asking questions, this is everywhere, from this site to Google: `awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"}; {print $1, $6, $7, $8, FILENAME}' infile1 infile2 infile3`

Comment: Hi Kos,my file is in zip format so i can't give infile1. and i don't want to first unzip the file.please suggest the other way.

Comment: Ok sorry, I missed that the file(s) were zipped. Does the zip file contain a single file or multiple files?

Comment: Zip file contain a single file.

Comment: Is that a zip/PKZIP file (compressed archive files, usually with a .zip extension and generally found on Microsoft operating systems) or a `compress`-compressed file (a very old compression (no archive) format (but still the only one specified by POSIX/Unix) usually using the `.Z` extension)?

Comment: yes it's compress-compressed file with .Z extension and i can read this file by zcat command in unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `.Z` file is a [`compress`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/compress.html)-compressed file (as the `.Z` extension implies as opposed to PKZIP archives that *zip file* would suggest):

```
FILE='OMS_Profile_20150922.list.Z'
export FILE
zcat < "$FILE" | awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '
  {print $1,$6,$7,$8, ENVIRON["FILE"]}'
```

Comment: On Solaris 10 and before, you may have to use `command -p awk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `nawk` instead of `awk` above.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
unzip -c /tmp/test.zip >/tmp/test.txt
awk -F "|" 'START {OFS="|"} {print $1,$6,$7,$8,FILENAME}' /tmp/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read s d t f_name < <(unzip -qql OMS_Profile_20150922.list.Z)
unzip -p OMS_Profile_20150922.list.Z | 
awk -F'|' '{print $1,$6,$7,$8,f_name}' OFS='|' f_name="$f_name"
```